# Display text from x time to x time (and it will be continue for next text) like presentation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to display text like presentation. I tried this code

```
setTimeout(fade_out, 2000);

function fade_out() {
$("#msg").fadeOut().empty();
}
```

and

```
<div id="msg"> John (First appear)</div>
<div id="msg"> Doe (Second appear)</div>
```

But it's only display and after that hidden the word

How to make the text appears and dissapears continuously (like function to appear at x time and dissapear at y time) because I only little understand about Javascript.

Example:

[image: First display]

[image: Second display]

Comment: Sounds like you might want to check out [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve this effect using CSS alone.

This is an entirely legitimate approach since CSS is responsible for the presentation layer in web documents.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  font-size: 6vw;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide-1 {
  animation: showSlide 3s linear 0s;
}

.slide-2 {
  animation: showSlide 3s linear 3s;
}

.slide-3 {
  animation: showSlide 3s linear 6s;
}

.slide-4 {
  animation: showSlide 3s linear 9s;
}

.slide-5 {
  animation: showSlide 3s linear 12s;
}

@keyframes showSlide {

    0% {opacity: 0;}
   20% {opacity: 1;}
   80% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<p class="slide slide-1">Hi!</p>
<p class="slide slide-2">We're setting things up for you</p>
<p class="slide slide-3">Getting there...</p>
<p class="slide slide-4">Just a little bit more...</p>
<p class="slide slide-5">Thanks for your patience.</p>
```

Comment: thanks, it works great, I not only can make a slideshow but also can set the timer, thank you very much

Comment: Great stuff. If you can upvote this answer as well, I would very much appreciate it. Thank you, @PalgunoWicaksono.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution with setInterval and also with clearInterval method when your "slideshow" finish it'll stop.

```js
let texts = [
  '<div class="text" id="text_1">Hi!</div>',
  '<div class="text" id="text_2">We`re setting things up for you</div>',
  '<div class="text" id="text_3">Text3</div>'
]

var i = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName('container')[0].innerHTML = texts[i];
  ++i;
  if(i == texts.length){
    window.clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById("text_"+i).style.cssText = "animation:1s fadeLast ease;opacity:1;"
  }
},1500)
```

```css
body{
  background: black;
  color:white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin:0
}

*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box
}

container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.text{
  font-size:2rem;
  opacity:0;
  animation: 1.5s fadeIn ease
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
  0%{opacity:0}
  50%{opacity:1}
  100%{opacity:0}
}

@keyframes fadeLast{
  from{opacity:0}
  to{opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<container></container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`fadeOut()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [`.fadeIn()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/). When you are changing value you can use `fadeIn()`

Please check below code snippet

```js
function setText() {
  $('#msg span').fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).text(new Date().toLocaleString())
  }).fadeIn();

  setTimeout(function() {
    setText();
  }, 2000);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  setText();
}, 2000);
```

```css
.msg{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;width:100%;height:122px}body{background:#000;color:#fff;font-family:sans-serif;margin:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="msg" class="msg">
  <span>Date time change start by every 2 second</span>
</div>
```